# jQuerys $(e.target) returns different things in Chrome and IE11

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I've made a codepen for you to see the misbehaving IE11:

http://codepen.io/timkley/pen/rjamgP

Basic setup is a form with a select field and a button. I want to catch the click on the form and only fire the submit button if the select button was NOT clicked.

```
<form class="form">
  <select class="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Hello</button>
</form>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.form', function(e) {
  console.log($(e.target));

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Basically all I did was check for `$(e.target).hasClass('select')` to `return false`. But this doesn't work in IE11 because not only doesn't it return the DOM Element but also fires 2 click events. One for the clicking on the select element and one for selecting an option.

How can I ensure the same behavior in both browsers?

Comment: Seems XY problem. What exactly you are trying to achieve? As you are binding click event handler to top element, the child elements click will propagate

Comment: Is there a reason you're listening for clicks on the entire form?

Comment: The whole form is designed to be the button of an ecommerce page, since it spans to the left and right of the quantity picker. When clicked on anything in this form, except the quantity picker, the button should be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're going this route but you can detect the tag type of the target and branch from there.

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.form', function(e) {
      var $target = $(e.target);
      var tag = $target[0].tagName.toLowerCase();

      if(tag !== "select" && tag !== "option"){
        console.log(tag + " isn't a select or an option");
      } else {
        console.warn(tag + " was clicked");
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <select class="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Hello</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind another click handler with select and use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.tagName + ' is clicked.');
}).on('click', '.form select', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.tagName + ' is clicked.');
}).on('click', '.form select', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <select class="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Hello</button>
</form>
```

Or, You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to test whether `e.target` is `select` or its child element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(e.target).closest('select').length) {
        console.log('Select is clicked do nothing.');
    } else {
        console.log(e.target.tagName + ' is clicked.');
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(e.target).closest('select').length) {
    console.log('Select is clicked do nothing.');
  } else {
    console.log(e.target.tagName + ' is clicked.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <select class="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Hello</button>
</form>
```